# non-VM operating system on hardware that supports virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

Is it possible to use OS without virtual memory support on the hardware with virtual memory support?

In other words, is it necessarily required for OS to support virtual memory if hardware uses virtual memory system?

For example, as far as I know, MS-DOS does not support virtual memory, however it runs on x86 processors with virtual memory support

Vice versa, is it possible to use OS that supports virtual memory, on the hardware without virtual memory support?

For example, embedded linux uses virtual memory, and is deployed on various architectures such as ARM, MIPS, SuperH, AVR; do they all support virtual memory system?

Thanks

Comment: Virtual memory (read: MMU) typically needs to be explicitly turned on at system startup. If the OS doesn't bother, CPU won't assume otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware *supports* virtual memory, that doesn't mean you have to use it. Operating systems *support* virtual memory, that doesn't mean they have to use it.

Comment: okay, I see, what I mean is that, is it possible NOT to use virtual memory in OS, on the hardware that supports virtual memory, and is it possible to USE virtual memory in OS, on the hardware that does NOT support virtual memory? :)

Comment: someone told me that even though the hardware may not support VM, it can be implemented within OS itself :\

Comment: @mangusta: If it can be implemented by the OS on a particular hardware platform, then that hardware platform supports it. (That's what it means to support virtual memory -- it means an OS can implement it.)

Comment: embedded linux uses virtual memory, but I've never heard about virtual memory support on ARM, MIPS, SuperH etc., Then you mean that embedded linux CAN use virtual memory but it will NOT use it on these partucular architectures?

Comment: Embedded Linux can use virtual memory. It is not possible to have virtual memory on hardware that does not support virtual memory.

Comment: okay :) now I got it, actually nowadays almost all hardware platforms support virtual memory, but it doesn't mean that OS has to necessarily implement it - it may or may not; for example microC/OS doesn't implement virtual memory system, and hence it has to use physical addresses of underlying hardware platform, although the latter may support VM. Thanks for reply